# send String from Activity to Fragments EditText

Tags: android

There is a button in my `ListViewFragment` who initiates a Scan. I scan the serialnumber and get the String in My `MainActivities` `onActivityResult` method (There is another Scan in my `MainActivity`. I get the string and I want to send the string back to my `ListViewFragment`to set it in an `EditText`. But I get a NullPointerException because my `ListViewFragment`wants to get the `serialFromScan`String wich is empty.
How can I provide that my Fragment calls the bundle AFTER the Serial was scanned?

Fragment:

```
inputSerial = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_serial);
        ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.button_scan_serial);
        ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE_128,DATA_MATRIX,ITF,CODABAR,EAN_13,EAN_8,UPC_A");
                getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 11);

                Bundle b = getArguments();
                String serialFromScan = b.getString("serialFromScan");
                Log.d("Seriennummerangekommen?", serialFromScan);


            }
        });
```

MainActivity:

```
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.scanbutton);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(intent,10);
        }
    });
```

[...]

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String scanContent = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                String scanFormat = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
                Log.d("INHALT", scanContent);
                Log.d("FORMAT", scanFormat);

                switch (requestCode){
                    case (10):{
                        String[] Split = scanContent.split("\\s");
                        String product = Split[0];
                        String label = Split[1];
                        String serial = Split[2];
                        String mac = Split[3];
                        String daaid = Split[4];
                        String bill = Split[5];

                        mydb.insertData(product, label, serial, mac, daaid, bill);
                        break;
                    }
                    case (11):{

                            scannedResult = scanContent;
                            serialScanned = true;
                            Bundle b = new Bundle();
                            b.putString("serialFromScan", scanContent);
                            ListViewFragment LvF = new ListViewFragment();
                            LvF.setArguments(b);

                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

                Log.d("TEST", "result_canceled");
            }

    }
```

Comment: Perhaps retrieve the string in the  View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) method in your fragment.

Comment: I tried but then he wants to receive the string on startup (when its empty)

Comment: If you want to do scans from within the already create fragment: create fragment with reference to activity > call activity to do scan (just a method on the activity) > listen for results on that method and show in it in the fragment. Is this the use-case?. The bundle is usually meant to send data on creation of the fragment :)

Comment: ahhh ok. Yes that is what I want to do

Comment: @Bram could you explain how to add the listener?

Comment: Perhaps there is also another way: I just saw that the fragment also has a startactivityforresult method. Could you try to call: this.startActivityForResult from the fragment and implement the onActivityResult in the fragment? Then you should be able to set the data received from the 'external scan activity' within the fragment and update the screen. In that case you do not need to bother the main activity with the scan functionality. The activity just starts the fragment and the fragments handles the scanning and showing. Sorry for pointing out different methods :)

Comment: But I need the `onActivityResult` in my `MainActivity`anyways (because of my second Scan). Is there realy no other way to send the string to my Fragment?

Comment: the second scan is not related to the fragment? Could you please elaborate on the use-case?

Comment: I added the code for the other scan. With this one (result code 10) I want to scan a QR Code. indepentent from the other scan in my `ListViewFragment`.

Answer (score 2):

write the startActivityForResult() after the bundle initialised.
try this answer..

```
inputSerial = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_serial);
    ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.button_scan_serial);
    ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE_128,DATA_MATRIX,ITF,CODABAR,EAN_13,EAN_8,UPC_A");

            Bundle b = getArguments();
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 11);

            String serialFromScan = b.getString("serialFromScan");
            Log.d("Seriennummerangekommen?", serialFromScan);


        }
    });
```

Comment: another method you may also send the data through a bundle

Comment: nope didnt nothing changed. The App is still crashing

Answer (score 1):

getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 11);

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("edttext", "From Activity");
// set Fragmentclass Arguments
Fragmentclass fragobj = new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

and in Fragment onCreateView method:

```
Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
String strtext = getArguments().getString("edttext");    
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

Comment: get the data from the bundle arguments

Comment: this is not the problem. I get the string but I have to get it AFTER my `MainActivity`sets it.